# Unstable wireless connection

Tags: 12.10, wireless, 64-bit, dell, broadcom

I have Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits kernel 3.5.0-22 running on a Dell Precision M6700. The wireless controller is a Broadcom BCM43228 (802.11abgn, the router also is 802.11abgn); it didn't install on a fresh install, so I added the **bcmwl-kernel-source package** and I got the wireless network working... sort of.
This is a dual boot machine, and under the same conditions that the connection running Windows is stable, running Linux it is anything but; every now and then it disconnects itself, it doesn't manage to connect on its own to the router, requiring a repeater (which is not necessary with Windows) and even then there are times when it connects to the network without really working (e.g. pinging the router itself returns "unreachable"). Frequently when reconnecting it asks the network password again. At times it doesn't manage to connect at all, even with the repeater turned on. Things only really work if I am practically stuck to the router, but that sort of defeats the whole idea of wireless connections.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.
Ken

Answer (score 0):

There's a program called NDISWrapper. It's in repo under ndisgtk. It will let you use windows XP drivers pretty seamlessly which is nice.

The broadcom cards are a total headache - the company is d-bags to open source and their proprietary linux drivers are far from reliable.

General recommendation - Wicd instead of Network-Manager. Good time to ditch Unity as well if you are still on it. Wicd has fixed persistent authentication problems, signal strength issues, etc with the Broadcom cards for me before.